# Hadoop Map-Reduce Output File Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, exception, mapreduce

I am getting this error on runing a single node hadoop cluster on amazon d2.2Xlarge.I also cannot view my output.Can anyone provide me with the proper steps to resolve this issue?

```
"Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not
 find any valid local directory for output/file.out"
```

This are my steps executed.

```
bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave                            
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /inputfiles    
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave    
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /output    
bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave       
bin/hadoop fs -put input1 /inputfiles    
bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave   
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar  
wordcount /inputfiles /output
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create output directory for Map Reduce job.

Remove this command

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /output
```

And change last command as

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar  
wordcount /inputfiles /output1
```

Make sure that you have permissions to create `output1` under /

If not, I would prefer below directory strucuture.

`/home/your_user_name/input` for input directory files and

`/home/your_user_name/output` for output directory.

Comment: ok..Even after removing the output mkdir it works fine for ..100Mb,300MB ,but not for 1GB..so is this a disk issue..?